# How to access element in html code

Tags: html, dom, data-structures, html-parsing, jericho-html-parser

1-What code i write to get all "**want to access**" element in this code no other element like "***some data***" and only want elements with in div class  **bestMFdtl2**.

2-and if i want some specific element with in this code according to choice how to do this, i am using html jerico parser.Please help me and those have problem reading code i am sorry for this but you are programmer i thought you like this.

3-How to get href link from the tags.

```
<div class='bestMFdtl2 '>
        <div class='tBrd btBrd tbg'>
         <div class='FL eqTle2 wd_182 rtBrd PL10 PR10'><a href='' class='bl_11'><strong></strong></a></div>
       <div class='FL eqTle wd_65 rtBrd PL5 PR5' align='center'><strong>some data</strong></div>
     <div class='FL eqTle wd_83 rtBrd' align='center'>
 <div class='btBrd'><strong>some data</strong> <span style='font-size:8px;'>some data</span></div>
        <div class='PT3'>some data</div>
        </div>
  <div class='FL eqTle wd_46 rtBrd btBrd' align='center'><strong>some data</strong></div>
    <div class='FL eqTle rtBrd'>
   <div align='center' class='btBrd'><strong>some data</strong></div>
    <table width='100%' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>
        <tr>
       <td align='center' width='56' height='20' class='rtBrd'><strong>some data <sup>some data</sup></strong></td>
       <td align='center' width='56' class='rtBrd'><strong>some data <sup>&nbsp;</sup></strong></td>
        <td align='center' width='56' class='rtBrd'><strong>some data <sup>&nbsp;</sup></strong></td>
        <td align='center' width='56' class='rtBrd'><strong>some data<sup>&nbsp;</sup></strong></td>
        <td align='center' width='56' class='rtBrd'><strong>some data<sup>*</sup></strong></td>
        <td align='center' width='56'><strong>some data <sup>*</sup></strong></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        </div>
        <div class='FL btBrd' style='width:43px;'></div>
        <div class='CL'></div>
        </div>
        <div class='equityN2'>
        <table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' style='margin-top:5px;'><tr>
        <td width='185'><div align='left'><a class='b-12' title='BNP Paribas Equity Fund (G)' href=''>Want to access</a> </div></td>
        <td width='70' nowrap=''><a href='' class='dgrey_12' target='_blank'>Rank 1</a><br><a href='/mf/crisil_methodology/' target='_blank'><span class='star'></span><span class='star'></span><span class='star'></span><span class='star'></span><span class='star'></span></a></td>
       <td width='70' style='text-align:right;'>127.22</td>
         <td width='40' style='text-align:right;'>42.03</td>
         <td class='#000000' width='48' style='text-align:right;'>--</td>
        <td class='grn' width='48' style='text-align:right;'>3.0</td>
        <td class='grn' width='48' style='text-align:right;'>10.3</td>
        <td class='grn' width='48' style='text-align:right;'>6.6</td>
         <td class='grn' width='50' style='text-align:right;'>18.9</td>
         <td class='grn' width='50' style='text-align:right;'>5.6</td>
        <td><A href='want to access' title='Download Form' target='_new' class='mfToolt'><img src='' alt=''></A></td>
         </tr><tr>
        <td width='185'><div align='left'><a class='b-12' title='' href='/'>want to access</a> </div></td>
        <td width='70' nowrap=''><a href='' class='dgrey_12' target='_blank'>Rank 1</a><br><a href='/mf/crisil_methodology/' target='_blank'><span class='star'></span><span class='star'></span><span class='star'></span><span class='star'></span><span class='star'></span></a></td>
        <td width='70' style='text-align:right;'>105.26</td>
        <td width='40' style='text-align:right;'>12.37</td>
        <td class='grn' width='48' style='text-align:right;'>0.7</td>
        <td class='grn' width='48' style='text-align:right;'>3.1</td>
        <td class='grn' width='48' style='text-align:right;'>8.8</td>
         <td class='grn' width='48' style='text-align:right;'>3.6</td>
        <td class='grn' width='50' style='text-align:right;'>16.1</td>
        <td class='grn' width='50' style='text-align:right;'>5.8</td>
        <td><A href='want to access' title='Download Form' target='_new' class='mfToolt'><img src='' alt=''></A></td>
        </tr>
```

Comment: fixed the question for you - but iam not going through this hell of code. Pls fix your code styling , so we can see where the problem is. I dont thing we need the full code - a short example will help :)

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking, but have a look at [document.getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName) and see if that helps with your problem

Comment: You seem to be asking about accessing multiple different things. The easiest way to do it would be to add ID's to your elements and then "document.getElementById". If that's not possible maybe try getting the parent element and pulling the list of href's from it.

Comment: Actually i want this from the live website that is not mine so i am not able to add id another way to access can you please explain by code

Comment: Getelementbyclass not working because it gives all the element and i only want every element in child class b-12 with in parent class bestMFdt12 @dbs

Comment: people not help just downgrade the rating here is this talent no way you must help a person? you people just concentrate more on downgrade ratings when you have no talent to clear the answer i hate this site completely No one ask you a question which is like a pie because this site have some standard then why you not able to solve a complex one .

Comment: If you want the elements inside a child class, get the parent class, then use getElementsByClassName again on the child class. e.g.   `var x = document.getElementsByClassName("bestMFdt12").getElementsByClassName("b-12")` I haven't tested it, but if I'm understanding right then that should do what you're asking.

Comment: yes you get it right now i first try it then let you know and thanks @DBS

Comment: source.getAllElementsByClass("b-12").get(i-1) how to get all element in class "b-12" ? the above code give only 1 st value this happens because i am passing  1 and if i am writing code as source.getAllElementsByClass("b-12") it shows error in red so i am confused how to get all element those are mention in class b-12 mention @DBS

Answer (score 0):

Given the comments, I believe this is what you're after.

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("bestMFdt12");

for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
    var x2 = x[i].getElementsByClassName("b-12");

    for (var j = 0; j < x2.length; j++) {
        //Do something with the elements, access them with "x2[j]", these loops will go through every element within both classes and allow you to process them

        //Example:
        var current = x2[j];
    }
}
```

This should, get an array of all the "bestMFdt12" elements, and for each one of those search inside for any "b-12" elements. Where I've put the example, you can add the code to process these elements.

Comment: thanks dbs you are right yesterday i resolved this problem i am showing you code Element Inform = source.getAllElementsByClass("bestMFdt12").get(i-1);
List<Element> Inform1  = Inform.getAllElementsByClass("b-12"); @dbs